# NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES does not include AspNetCore folder in Linux ASP.NET Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I've got Docker Desktop 24.0.6 installed on a Windows machine.

I created a simple .NET console application, setting the *Sdk* in *.csproj* to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` to ensure we get a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework. This is the *.csproj* file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the application code in *Program.cs*:

```
Console.WriteLine(AppContext.GetData("NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES"));
```

In my application I need the `NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES` named data element to include the paths to both the .Net Core *and* the ASP.NET Core frameworks. Also, I'm running my application in a Docker container. Here is the *Dockerfile* used to build the image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
COPY MyApp MyApp
RUN dotnet publish --output out MyApp

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS final
COPY --from=build out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

I build the image with the tag *native-dll-dirs* and run it using the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm native-dll-dirs
```

With Docker Desktop set to Windows containers, I get the following output:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.22\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\;
```

This is as expected.
However, with Docker Decktop set to Linux containers, I get this output:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.22/:
```

The ASP.NET Core folder is clearly missing from the named data element, even though I can confirm that the folder */usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.22/* does exist in the container!

I have two questions:

- Why is the ASP.NET Core folder not included in the `NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES` value when running in the Linux container? Could it be an error in the *mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0* image that I'm using? It is the same with the *7.0* and *8.0* images as well.
- My application needs these two folder paths. How can I work around this issue to get hold of them?